# Facing trouble while plotting continuous curve using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was using `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot a continuous curve in jupyter notebook. I used the following code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.reshape(-1,1), y, random_state = 0)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=9)
X_train_p = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_p = poly.fit_transform(X_test)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.title("deg={}".format(9))
plt.plot(X_train, y_train.reshape(-1,1), 'r')
plt.show()
```

I expected the data points to be successively connected by straight lines, however the outcome turns up like this: [image]

I tried multiple variations of reshaping `X_train` and `y_train` using `.reshape()`, but didn't get the expected outcome.

Comment: sort the values and plot them. .